# Php asks for user name and password twice

Tags: php

I wrote this php script:

```
<?
session_start();

if(isset($_GET["logout"])) {
unset($_SESSION["user"]);
unset($_SESSION["user_token"]);
echo "successful logout";
die;
}

if(!isset($_SESSION["user_token"])){
$GETusername = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"];
$GETpassword = $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"];
$users = array(
    'user' => 'pass',
    'user2' => 'pass2',
    'user3' => 'pass3'
);
$user = isset($GETusername) ? strtolower($GETusername) : '';
$pass = isset($GETpassword) ? $GETpassword : '';
$config["admin_username"] = $user;
$config["admin_passowrd"] = $pass;
header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Login\"");
if (!isset($users[$user]) or $users[$user] != $pass) {
    ?>
    wrong username or password!
    <?
    die;
}
$_SESSION["user"] = $config["admin_username"];
$_SESSION["user_token"] =   
"auth-".md5($config["admin_username"]).md5($config["admin_passowrd"]);
die;
}
echo "username: ".$_SESSION["user"]."<br /><a href='?logout'>logout</a>";
?>
```

When I try to log in for the **first** time I have to type my username and password **twice** (as if I typed wrong pass or username)! But when I logout and try to login again, everything is normal! Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

add session_start above your script

```
 session_start();
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, first two lines in my code wasn't visible in this question. I fix it. But problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! 
I do not really know how, but it works now!